# How to make table view cells scroll "under" instead of over other elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working with `UITableView`, but when I "pull" the tableview up to see other cells that are "hiding", it pulls over my logo and a label that I want to be constantly showing. Can I:

1. either fixate the tableview so it doesn't get pulled out of its intended frame, or
2. make it scroll under the elements i want to be constantly shown.

Thanks!

Comment: Codes ? What have you tried?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/b6VoqFk.png I dont know if this explains it better. I have here pulled the table up and it covers the label and logo behind it. I have not really tried anything other than making constraints between the elements. Im still pretty new to iOS dev. hence my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Storyboard, move your tableview above the logo and UILabel.
Or send your tableview to back using

```
- (void)sendSubviewToBack:(UIView *)view;
```

Comment: Whats the logic behind moving the tableview above the other elements. You can see my storyboard here: http://imgur.com/KIOZGoJ
I have started from top first putting the orange bar, then grey label, then the tableview and then the bottom "navigation" view. I then put in constraints between all of them (including a constraint from the navi bar to the bottom layer of view. Yet when tableview has many cells it somehow pushes the navi-bar out of the screen when run. (the sendSubviewToBack: worked for the top part)

Comment: In your case Orange bar , above that grey label will be added and above that your tableview will be added. Since tableview is above Orange bar and grey label ,it will hide those if the y position of your tableview changes. But if you move your tableview above these views in storyboard. In the view hierarchy,tableview will be at the bottom. even if your tableview y position changes, it will not hide Orange bar or grey label.

Comment: I thought you were talking about the storyboard view itself, which got me a little confused. Obv you meant the view hierarchy:) Thanks again